# Win32 ListView - handle invalid after LVM_INSERTITEM

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi, sendmessage

I have a problem a window handle (window class = WC_LISTVIEW) after calling

```
SendMessage(hListView_, LVM_INSERTITEM , 0, (LPARAM)&lvItem);
```

where

```
hListView_
```

is a handle to a list view window and

```
lvItem
```

is an LVITEM structure. The following code

```
std::cout << "Last error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
SendMessage(hListView_, LVM_INSERTITEM , 0, (LPARAM)&lvItem);
std::cout << "Last error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

prints

```
Last error: 0
Last error: 6
```

According to [Win32 System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) code 6 means ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE.

I create the LVITEM structure as follows:

```
// define a char-buffer
char szBuffer[256];
szBuffer[0] = '\0';

// create new list view item
LVITEM lvItem;
lvItem.cchTextMax = 256;
lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
lvItem.iItem = 0;
lvItem.stateMask = 0;
lvItem.state = 0;
lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
snprintf(szBuffer, 256, "%s", myString.c_str());
lvItem.pszText = szBuffer;
```

This code is called from the same thread which created the window (list view).
Also note that I have

```
lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
```

which is required according to [LVM_INSERTITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761107(v=vs.85).aspx). The list view is empty prior to this call. Moreover, I can actually see the value being inserted in the list view (i.e. I can see the item in the list view in the GUI).
However, when I try to use the window handle after this the application crashes (no exception, just crashes).

Greatful for any hints on what might cause this.

Thank you.

Comment: Your error checking code is broken.  It is only ever valid to call GetLastError() when the function you call says that it failed and the MSDN documentation says that you can use GetLastError() to find out why.  That's a problem with SendMessage(), it doesn't.  The LVM_INSERTITEM message doesn't make any promises.  You can only get -1 back, just an "it didn't work" indication.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It seems the root of the problem might lie elsewhere then. The application crash (and error  code 6) only appears when calling SendMessage, so maybe it's something else that interfers.

Comment: @HansPassant: `SendMessage()` does have one defined error code using `GetLastError()`: "When a message is blocked by UIPI the last error, retrieved with GetLastError, is set to 5 (access denied)."  So, you could do something like `SetLastError(0); if (SendMessage(hListView_, LVM_INSERTITEM , 0, (LPARAM)&lvItem) == 0) { err = GetLastError(); if (err != 0) ...}`.

Comment: @HansPassant: Otherwise, if you want more accurate error checking, consider using [`SendMessageCallback()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644951.aspx) instead. It returns a `BOOL` indicating whether `SendMessageCallback()` itself succeeded or failed, reporting an error code with `GetLastError()` if FALSE.  If TRUE, the message result is passed to a callback function that you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you David Heffernan for your help. I did at last find the problem, which was (as you suggested) in a different place in the code.

I had missed the following line (in a different function which I call prior to the code I posted above)

```
lvItem.pszText = szBuffer;
```

where

```
char szBuffer[256]; // char-buffer
```

when doing the follwing call

```
SendMessage(hListView_, LVM_GETITEMTEXT, (WPARAM) i, (LPARAM) &lvItem);
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Edit: If I had done

```
lvItem.pszText = myString.c_str();
```

rather than the char-buffer this would probably not have happened, so thanks for that hint!

Answer (score -1):

There's no reason for you to call `GetLastError`. The documentation for `LVM_INSERTITEM` doesn't say that you should do so. All it says is that `SendMessage` returns the index of the new item on success, and -1 on failure. So, check for errors by inspecting the value returned by `SendMessage`.

The other problem is that you are not initialising all the fields of `LVITEM`. That's always a mistake. You can use an initialising declaration like this:

```
LVITEM lvItem = { 0 };
```

There's no real need for a separate buffer for the text. You can do it all like this:

```
LVITEM lvItem = { 0 };
lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
lvItem.cchTextMax = myString.length() + 1;
lvItem.pszText = myString.c_str();
int indexOfNewItem = SendMessage(hListView_, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&lvItem);
if (indexOfNewItem == -1)
    // deal with failure
```

It's quite possible that your error lies elsewhere in fact. I don't see any particular reason for that `SendMessage` call to lead to an application crash. At least now you know how to check for errors when sending `LVM_INSERTITEM`. If that does not result in an error then the evidence would be that the crash is caused by some other code and you have mistakenly identified this code because you erroneously called `GetLastError` when its value was meaningless.

Comment: Hi, I tried the changes you proposed, unfortunately this did not help. I get indexOfNewItem equal to 0, i.e. the SendMessage call does not indicate any errors. Maybe I should mention also: this code is called from the window procedure of the parent window to the list view window.

Comment: Then your problem is elsewhere. However, it is wrong to say that my answer doesn't help. You now how how to check for errors properly, and how to initialize all members of the struct.

Comment: I did not mean that your answer was not helpful. There shouldn't be any issues with this code executing from the parent window's window procedure, right?

Comment: No. If the call to `SendMessage` returns `0` then that means that the item was successfully inserted. You need to identify the real problem now.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could the following cause it? I have a background thread which creates a vector of strings. This vector is then moved (std::move) into a global variable (class variable, but equivalent to global in this case). Then, this background thread sends a user-defined message (WM_APP + 2) by PostMessage to the list view's parent window. This message handler in the parent window's wnd proc then calls the code which updates the listview.

Comment: I know that you want to solve your problem, but you asked this question, and I answered this question, as I saw best. I'm not going to speculate on some other code that I cannot see that you describe vaguely. Feel free to make a concise repro and ask another question.

Comment: I think I answered the question that you asked. I'm not sure what to make of your answer. I think you need to distinguish between the answer to the question you asked, and the solution to your actual problem.

Comment: I'm aware that my answer is not directly related. The problem is that my question/problem was not related to the solution of the problem (as you stated). Thank you very much for your help,

Comment: You don't really understand what this site is about

Comment: Sorry, I will keep in mind to distinguish between question asked and my problem.

Comment: I do think I answered the question you asked.